# SwipeRefreshLayout + ViewPager with Fragments not working

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, android-tablayout, swiperefreshlayout

I have implemented the SwipeRefreshLayout in many of the pages,and it working fine. but here i got stuck with one specific implementation , where i have a SwipeRefreshLayout for the ViewPager and ViewPager holding the FragmentPagerAdapter.

In my case , I have a ViewPager with two tabs and each holding the fragment with RecyclerView. On main page I have a SwipeRefreshLayout and on the onRefresh i need to load the API and update the fragments in ViewPager. Updating is working fine but unfortunately RecyclerView inside the Fragment ( ViewPager tab Item ) not scrolling top and it always calling the SwipeToRefresh.

I am familiar with using the  SwipeRefreshLayout with RecyclerView, but here the problem is the main child of the SwipeRefreshLayout  is ViewPager and it having the Fragment inside it and that fragment is holding the RecyclerView.

I have a thought of moving the SwipeRefreshLayout inside the fragments for the RecyclerView , but again here i have challenges like both the Fragments is having the same API. So that i am using the SwipeRefreshLayout directly on ViewPager to refresh my data.

Here is some of my codes.

MainContacts.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll_no_records"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:visibility="gone">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_retry"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"

            android:contentDescription="@string/todo"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_reload" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textError"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/no_contact_found"
            android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
            android:textColor="@color/colorDarkGray" />


    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll_process"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:alpha="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:visibility="visible">


        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progress"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:indeterminate="true" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/fetching"
            android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
            android:textColor="@color/colorDarkGray" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/swipeRefreshLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/contacts_screen"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/my_contacts_tabs"
                style="@style/MyCustomTabLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                app:tabBackground="@color/colorWhite"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                android:id="@+id/my_contacts_view_pager"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0px"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent" >
            </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

contacts.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:hc="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/ll_no_records"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:visibility="gone">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_retry"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:contentDescription="@string/todo"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_reload" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textError"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/no_contact_found"
        android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
        android:textColor="@color/colorDarkGray" />


</LinearLayout>

<com.diegocarloslima.fgelv.lib.FloatingGroupExpandableListView
    android:id="@+id/contactList"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/searchContainer"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
    android:childDivider="@android:color/transparent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

MainFragment ( Which i am using to load the child fragments  , SwipeTORefreshLayout + ViewPager here)

```
public class MainFragment extends BaseFragment {

    private TextView mTextError;

    private LinearLayout llNoRecords, ll_process;
    private ImageView iv_retry;
    private MaterialSearchView materialSearchView;
    PHCJsonResponseContactDetailModel mContactResponseModel;
    int expandableListSelectionType = ExpandableListView.PACKED_POSITION_TYPE_NULL;
    boolean actionModeEnabled;
    private Activity mActivity;

    SwipeRefreshLayout mSwipeRefreshLayout;
    private ViewPager viewPager;
    TabLayout tabLayout;
    ContactsTabPagerAdapter mAdapter;

    ArrayList<PHCContactDetailModel> mContactList =new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<PHCContactDetailModel> mFavoriteList;

    boolean isSwipeToRefresh;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        mActivity = getActivity();
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.phc_contact_fragment, container, false);

        getViewId(view);
        setListener();
        if (isNetworkAvailable()) {
            if(((MainDrawerActivity)mActivity).getPHCContactFragmentData()==null)
            getAllContactData();
            else
                updateWidgets();
        } else {
            showNoNetworkToast();
            llNoRecords.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            mTextError.setText(getResources().getText(R.string.no_internet_retry));
        }
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);


    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

    }

    /*@Override
    public void onPrepareOptionsMenu(final Menu menu) {
        getActivity().getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_fragment_group, menu);

    }*/

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {

        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_fragment_contacts, menu);
        MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
        materialSearchView.setMenuItem(item);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if (item.getItemId() == R.id.action_create_group) {
            Intent createGroupIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), PHCCreateGroupActivity.class);
            createGroupIntent.putExtra("comeFrom", PHCAppConstant.GROUP_ADD);
            getActivity().startActivity(createGroupIntent);
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    private void setListener() {
        iv_retry.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (isNetworkAvailable()) {
                    getAllContactData();
                } else {
                    showNoNetworkToast();
                }
            }
        });

    }

    private void getViewId(View view) {

        mTextError = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textError);
        ll_process = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.ll_process);

        llNoRecords = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.ll_no_records);
        iv_retry = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.iv_retry);

        viewPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.my_contacts_view_pager);
        tabLayout = (TabLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.my_contacts_tabs);

        mSwipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.swipeRefreshLayout);

        mSwipeRefreshLayout.setColorSchemeResources(R.color.colorPrimary,
                android.R.color.holo_green_dark,
                android.R.color.holo_orange_dark,
                android.R.color.holo_blue_dark);


        mSwipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRefresh() {

                if(mContactResponseModel!=null && mContactResponseModel.getData().size() >0)
                {
                    isSwipeToRefresh = true;
                    getAllContactData();
                }
            }
        });


        materialSearchView = (MaterialSearchView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.search_view);

    }

    private void getAllContactData() {
        if (isNetworkAvailable()) {
//            showProgress();
            PHCApiInterface apiService = PHCApiClient.getClient(getActivity()).create(PHCApiInterface.class);
            Call<PHCJsonResponseContactDetailModel> call = apiService.contactData(getApplicationData(getActivity()).getAuthToken(), getApplicationData(getActivity()).getUserID());
            call.enqueue(new Callback<PHCJsonResponseContactDetailModel>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<PHCJsonResponseContactDetailModel> call, Response<PHCJsonResponseContactDetailModel> response) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "getContacts URL " + response.raw().request().url());
                    Log.d(TAG, "getContacts Resp " + new Gson().toJson(response.body()));
                    mContactResponseModel = response.body();
                    ((MainDrawerActivity)mActivity).setPHCContactFragmentData(mContactResponseModel);

                    if(mSwipeRefreshLayout.isRefreshing())
                    {
                        // cancel the Visual indication of a refresh
                        mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
                    }
                    if(isSwipeToRefresh)
                    {
                            isSwipeToRefresh=false;
                            updateWidgets();
                    }
                    else
                    updateWidgets();
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<PHCJsonResponseContactDetailModel> call, Throwable t) {

                    if(mSwipeRefreshLayout.isRefreshing())
                    {
                        // cancel the Visual indication of a refresh
                        mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
                    }
                    isSwipeToRefresh=false;
                    dismissProgress();
                    mTextError.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            });
        } else {

            isSwipeToRefresh=false;

            if(mSwipeRefreshLayout.isRefreshing())
            {
                // cancel the Visual indication of a refresh
                mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
            }

            showNoNetworkAlert();
        }
    }

    private void updateWidgets() {

        if (mContactResponseModel.getStatusCode() == 401 || mContactResponseModel.getStatusCode() == 402) {
            showSessionExpireAlert(mContactResponseModel.getStatusMessage(), mContactResponseModel.getStatusCode());
            return;
        }
        if (mContactResponseModel != null && mContactResponseModel.getStatusCode() == 1) {
            dismissProgress();
            mTextError.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            mContactList = mContactResponseModel.getData();
            mFavoriteList = mContactResponseModel.getData();

            if(mContactList!=null && mContactList.size()>0)
            {
                llNoRecords.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                mAdapter = new ContactsTabPagerAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), getChildFragmentManager(), mContactList , mFavoriteList);

                viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
                tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
            }
            else {
                llNoRecords.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }

        } else {
            dismissProgress();
            mTextError.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }


    public void dismissProgress() {
        ll_process.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        super.dismissProgress();
    }


    private void initiateContactChat(final PHCFacilityDetailsModel facilityDetailsModel, final int groupPosition, final int childPosition) {
        String header = getApplicationData(getActivity()).getAuthToken();
        PHCApiInterface apiService = PHCApiClient.getClient(getActivity()).create(PHCApiInterface.class);
        Call<PHCContactInitiateChatResponseModel> call = apiService.initiateContactChat(header, facilityDetailsModel.getUserId(), getApplicationData(getActivity()).getUserID(), 0);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<PHCContactInitiateChatResponseModel>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<PHCContactInitiateChatResponseModel> call, Response<PHCContactInitiateChatResponseModel> response) {
                Log.d(TAG, "initiateContactChat URL " + response.raw().request().url());
                Log.d(TAG, "initiateContactChat Resp " + new Gson().toJson(response.body()));
                PHCContactInitiateChatResponseModel mContactInitiateChatModel = response.body();
                if (mContactInitiateChatModel != null && mContactInitiateChatModel.getStatusCode() == 1) {
                    Intent chatIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), PHCChatActivity.class);
//                    chatIntent.putExtra("headerName",mData.get(groupPosition).getFacilityDetails().get(childPosition).getUserName());
                    chatIntent.putExtra("headerName", facilityDetailsModel.getUserName());
                    chatIntent.putExtra("groupId", mContactInitiateChatModel.getData().getGroupId());
                    getActivity().startActivity(chatIntent);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<PHCContactInitiateChatResponseModel> call, Throwable t) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Something went wrong! Please try again", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }

}
```

ContactsTabPagerAdapter.java

```
public class ContactsTabPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    /**
     * The Page count.
     */
    final int PAGE_COUNT = 2;

    private String[] tabTitles = { "Contacts", "Favorites" };

    private ArrayList<PHCContactDetailModel> mContactsList;
    private ArrayList<PHCContactDetailModel> mFavoritesList;

    Context mContext ;

    public ContactsTabPagerAdapter(Context context, FragmentManager fm ,ArrayList<PHCContactDetailModel> contacts , ArrayList<PHCContactDetailModel> favs) {
        super(fm);
        this.mContext = context;
        this.mContactsList = contacts;
        this.mFavoritesList=favs;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {

        switch (position) {

            case 0:

                ContactsFragment mContactsFragment =new ContactsFragment();
                Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
                bundle.putSerializable("Contacts", (Serializable) mContactsList);

                mContactsFragment.setArguments(bundle);

                return mContactsFragment;

            case 1:

                FavoritesFragment mFavoritesFragment=new FavoritesFragment();

                Bundle pastBundle=new Bundle();
                pastBundle.putSerializable("Favorites", (Serializable) mFavoritesList);

                mFavoritesFragment.setArguments(pastBundle);

                return mFavoritesFragment;
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 2;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        // Generate title based on item position
        return tabTitles[position];
    }

    /**
     * Update.
     *
     * @param lContactsList  contact list to update
     * @param lFavoritesList  favorites list to update
     */
//call this method to update fragments in ViewPager dynamically
    public void update(ArrayList<PHCContactDetailModel> lContactsList, ArrayList<PHCContactDetailModel> lFavoritesList) {

        this.mContactsList = lContactsList;
        this.mFavoritesList = lFavoritesList;

        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
        if (object instanceof UpdatableFragment) {
            ((UpdatableFragment) object).update(mContactsList, mFavoritesList);
        }
        //don't return POSITION_NONE, avoid fragment recreation.
        return super.getItemPosition(object);
    }
}
```

ContactsFragment.java

```
public class ContactsFragment extends BaseFragment implements UpdatableFragment{

    private static final String TAG = "ContactFragmentTab";
    private FloatingGroupExpandableListView mContactExpandableList;
    private PHCContactAdapter mAdapter;
    WrapperExpandableListAdapter wrapperAdapter;
    boolean actionModeEnabled;
    private LinearLayout llNoRecords;
    private ArrayList<PHCContactDetailModel> mContactsData;

    public ContactsFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);


    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_contacts, container, false);

        getViewId(rootView);

        Bundle bundle= getArguments();

        if(bundle !=null)
        {
            Log.d(TAG, "bundle is not empty");

            mContactsData= (ArrayList<PHCContactDetailModel>) bundle.getSerializable("Contacts");
        }
        System.out.print("Contacts Size::" + mContactsData.size());

        if(mContactsData!=null)
        {
            updateWidgets();
        }

        return rootView;
    }

    private void updateWidgets() {

        mAdapter = new PHCContactAdapter(getActivity(), mContactsData, new ListShowingHidingListener() {
            @Override
            public void listHideAndShow(boolean isData) {
                if (isData) {
                    llNoRecords.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    mContactExpandableList.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    listUpdate();
                } else {
                    llNoRecords.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    mContactExpandableList.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            }
        });

        wrapperAdapter = new WrapperExpandableListAdapter(mAdapter);

        mContactExpandableList.setAdapter(wrapperAdapter);
        try {
            for (int i = 0; i < wrapperAdapter.getGroupCount(); i++) {
                mContactExpandableList.expandGroup(i);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Exception in Expand", "" + e);
        }

    }

    private void listUpdate() {
        try {
            for (int i = 0; i < wrapperAdapter.getGroupCount(); i++) {
                mContactExpandableList.expandGroup(i);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Exception in Expand", "" + e);
        }
    }

    private void getViewId(View view) {
        //   mContactExpandableList = (ExpandableListView) view.findViewById(R.id.contactList);
        mContactExpandableList = (FloatingGroupExpandableListView) view.findViewById(R.id.contactList);



    }


    @Override
    public void update(ArrayList<PHCContactDetailModel> contactsData, ArrayList<PHCContactDetailModel> favoritesData) {

        this.mContactsData = contactsData;
        updateWidgets();
    }
}
```

similarly i have Favorites example as well. Mostly both will look like same, that's why not posting it here.

Sorry for posting the long question. Any help regarding this. Apologies for my poor English. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I think issue this is SwipeRefreshLayout contain Tablayout and ViewPager

Comment: Yes. I solved the problem, vll post the answer in sometime

Comment: if you resolve this issue, please share your ans with us Thank You!